# Android EditText: Check if whitespace not at beginning or end

Tags: java, android, string

I have an input field where the user has to enter his forename and his surname.
Now I want to check whether there is a whitespace which is neither at the beginning nor at the end of the input. Only in this case, a button is enabled.

Checking the whitespace is easy:

```
private EditText input;
input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);  

if(input.getText().toString().contains(" ")) {
   button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

But how can I make sure that the whitespace is not at the beginning or end of the input?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

**EDITED**

```
String str = input.getText().toString();
if (str.contains(" ") && (!str.startsWith(" ") && !str.endsWith(" ")) )
    button.setEnabled(true);
```

Or

```
  if ( !(Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(0)) && Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(str.length()-1)) ) )
     button.setEnabled(true);
```

Also you can use a combination of `trim()` and `contains`:

```
if(str.trim().contains(" ")) 
  button.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: For whom had vote down my answer.Can you explain your reason please?

Comment: Doesn't really help because this code just checks whether there are only whitespaces.

Comment: this just trims the whitespaces out

Comment: Will work now, but could be better by doing:
if(str.trim().contains(" "))
so you get rid of the start and end spaces, and check for spaces in the middle :)

Comment: But when you use trim, it will remove ALL whitespaces no matter what.  So there's no way it will `contains(" ")`

Comment: @AbAppletic I tested it at the moment. The `trim()` just remove space at the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

**code**

```
if(input.getText().toString().substring(0,1).contains(" "))
    System.out.println("failed");
else if((input.getText().substring((input.getText().length() -1),(input.getText().toString().length())).contains(" ")))
    System.out.println("failed");
else
    System.out.println("success");
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I overreact. But if you use `.length() -1` it will get the character before the last one.

Comment: Since I don't know what you intended or if I'm wrong, I'm not going to edit the post, but downvote it. I'll remove the downvote when I get informed or you fix it :)

Comment: i test this and works fine for me. you can test it too :)

Comment: also when i code it was JTextField which don't need toString method after getText. but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String input = textview.getText().toString();

if(input.subString(1,input.length()-1).contains(" "))
    button.setEnabled(false);
else
    button.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    eingabe.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int before,int count){ }
       @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count,int after){ }
       @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
           weiterFertig.setEnabled(
                   s.length()>0&&!s.toString().startsWith(" ")&&!s.toString().endsWith(" ")&&s.toString().contains(" ")
           )
           ;
       }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
result = input.getText().toString();
if(result.subString(0,1) == " "){
...
   }
if(result.substring(result.length() - 0) == " "{
...
}
```

I hope this helps